# How to make the panels inside a TabPanel shrink/expand with the window size

Tags: extjs, layout, scrollbar, overflow, panel

I have a TabPanel layout with an hbox layout inside it. Pane1 shows a vertical scrollbar but doesn't cover the all the items. How can I resize all these contents as per the window resize.

```
 Ext.define('MyPanel', {
        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',        
        layout: 'vbox',
        initComponent: function() {
            this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                items: [                            
                Ext.create('AddressBar')
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [                            
                Ext.create('MyApp.view.Panel1'),
                Ext.create('MyApp.view.Panel2')
                ]
            }                      
            ];

            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });
```

//PANEL 1 with the scrollbar issue

```
Ext.define('Panel1', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    autoScroll: true,
    minWidth: 250,
    minHeight: 500,
    maxHeight: 1000,
    bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px',
    initComponent: function () {
        var thisPanel = this;
        var items = [{      
            xtype: 'panel',
            overflowY: 'auto',
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'checkbox',
                boxLabel: 'LodeData'                
            },
            {
                xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                id: 'group',
                labelWidth: 150,
                overflowY: 'auto',
                items: [
                { 
                    name: 'check1',
                    checked: true
                },
                { 
                    name: 'check2',
                    checked: true
                },
                { 
                    name: 'check3',
                    checked: true
                },                  
                ]                   
                layout: {
                    // align: 'stretch',
                    type: 'vbox',
                    pack: 'start'
                }
            }]
        }           
        ];
        this.items = items;
        this.callParent();
    }   

});
```

Comment: Before I come with an answer I want you to point some interesting information.

First of all you should never instance on a prototype:
https://sencha.guru/2015/07/29/instances-on-prototype-are-bad/

Second, you are way overnesting. There is no need to put a panel in a panel in a panel.

Third thing I would like to say is that you could consider using a form instead of a panel. Otherwise you could use a container instead of a panel. Use the highest possible component in hierarchy.

I think that if you remove the overnesting things will fall in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Tarabass for the detailed answer. I'll keep it in mind next time I design something. For now, I ressolved my issue by using flex

Comment: Great! Glad you figured it out yourself.